# grunt serve aborted due to warnings in yeoman mean

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs

I was following a tutorial on mean.io, and in it, i had to install `yo angular`

after sometime everything was installed and finally the i had to run `grunt serve'

then this error/warning comes

```
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/MeanApp/client$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh -c compass --version
/bin/sh: 1: compass: not found
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-07-16 10:01:13 UTC)
loading tasks                  10ms  ▇▇▇▇ 12%
loading grunt-contrib-compass  33ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 40%
compass:server                 38ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 46%
Total 82ms Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-07-16 10:01:12 UTC)
loading tasks                 10ms  ▇ 1%
loading grunt-contrib-clean   10ms  ▇ 1%
clean:server                   9ms  ▇ 1%
wiredep:app                  185ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 24%
wiredep:test                  10ms  ▇ 1%
wiredep:sass                  12ms  ▇ 2%
loading grunt-concurrent       9ms  ▇ 1%
concurrent:server            515ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 67%
Total 766ms
mukund@mukund-ThinkPad-Edge-E431:~/MeanApp/client$
```

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPFgqHz68o

Ans when i ran with this command `grunt serve --force`

I got the required page @ htttp://localhost/9000/#/ page with without any style

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install [compass](http://compass-style.org/install/). It is used by the SASS which is included in the angular yeoman generator.

If you have ruby installed you can do.

```
gem install compass
```

And don't use `--force` ever. Its not really meant for all the cases but grunt throws it for every error/warning except fatal errors.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaakzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: In Ubuntu, not even having Ruby installed: `sudo apt-get install ruby-compass`

Comment: `sudo gem install compass` if you're not root/admin as you will get warnings that you do not have permission.